# Traversing DOM to find which element has focus

Tags: javascript, traversal

I know how to do this in jQuery, but how to do it in Javascript?

```
    if ((evt.which == arrLeftKey || evt.keyCode == arrLeftKey) && document.getElementById(TopMenuID).getElementsByTagName('a') === document.activeElement) {
                alert("LEFT");
}
```

The above if statement isn't working, and I'm not really sure why.  Nothing is being alerted.  I have a nav bar called TopMenuID and if one of the a tags inside of it have focus, I want to alert LEFT when the left key is pressed.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `document.getElementById(TopMenuID).getElementsByTagName('a')` **`[0]`**

Comment: The `getElementsByTagName()` function returns a NodeList, which will never be equal to a single element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName('a')` returns an array, but you are comparing it to `activeElement` thus the two will NEVER be equal.

If you want to know if the activeElement is in your menu, then you can look up the parent chain of the activeElement and just see if you run into the TopMenuID element.

```
function doesContain(item, parent) {
    var obj = item.parentNode;
    while (obj && obj !== document.documentElement && obj.nodeType !== 11) {
        if (obj === parent) {
            return(true);
        }
        obj = obj.parentNode;
    }
    return(false);
}

if ((evt.which == arrLeftKey || evt.keyCode == arrLeftKey) && doesContain(document.activeElement, document.getElementById(TopMenuID) {
    alert("LEFT");
}
```

Comment: so, something like document.activeElement.parentNode === document.getElementById(TopMenuID)?

Comment: @Hubrid - Yes, something like that if the link is always only one level below topMenuID.  I added code to my answer that is more generic since you didn't share your HTML so I didn't know what assumptions could be made about the structure.

Comment: Updated the code to make it a little more broadly useful and bulletproof.

Answer (score 2):

Change it to

```
document.getElementById(TopMenuID).getElementsByTagName('a')[0]
```

Comment: doesn't this only give the first a in TopMenuID?

Comment: @Hubrid - Yes. Or else you can't compare it to `document.activeElement` because `getElementsByTagName` returns a NodeList (Array) and `activeElement` is a single Element.

Comment: ok, i need it to get any of them, but not the array of all of them, so i think jfriend00's answer works then

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.getElementById(TopMenuID).getElementsByTagName('a')[0]
```